# Global Function timeout in WebJobs

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am using the webjobs sdk 2.0 beta2. I see that the global function timeout in JobHostConfiguration was removed by this change list: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/commit/6a1fb9a748deebc68964d7ec2981b9bbdadcdc8d

Is there some other way to set the global function timeout, or should we only rely on function level timeout attribute?

Related question, can the function timeout attribute resolve the timeout value through INameResolver (similar to ServiceBusTrigger)? I need to set the timeout value through app configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can set web job timeout value in application setting. like below snippet code.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT" value="100000" />
    <add key="WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT" value="100000" />
</appSettings>
```

We could also set it in Azure Web app App setting.

[image]